# How can I shutdown Rocksdb completely?

Tags: rocksdb

I'm using Rocksdb in an application and after closing down all of the db instances, I still see threads with this running
rocksdb::ThreadPoolImpl::Impl::BGThread(unsigned long) ()

So when I shutdown the application I receive a libc++abi.dylib: terminating
error which i believe is due to the above.
How can I avoid this and make sure those threads are shutdown?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

There are a bunch of background process running in rocksdb like, Compaction, memtable flush which are handled by separate threads. To safely close ROCKSDB, you have to cancel all the background jobs running.

```
CancelAllBackgroundWork(bool);
```

Call this function, before closing the db. Pass a bool as argument, whether you want to terminate immediately or wait for the background jobs to complete and then terminate.

Calling `rocksdb_close()` now will shutdown the DB completely